# Windows autorun scripts with environment variables

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I have a package which should be deployed to several machines; contained within are several processes which should run when the user logs in. Due to the fact that some of these machines have minor differences, I have the following init-script which should be run once when the package is first installed.

**init.bat**

```
@ECHO off
REG ADD "HKCU\Environment" /v SYSCONFIG /d "%cd%" /f
```

This runs as expected, and sets the `SYSCONFIG` variable for the user to wherever the package was installed. Next, I make add some startup scripts using a `.reg` file; the idea here being that on each successive login, these scripts will be run, no matter the location of the package; using the variable as the path.

**autorun.reg**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
"MYSCRIPT"="%SYSCONFIG%\\Utils\\startup.bat"
```

The issue I am facing is that my `startup.bat` file is never executed. It seems as if environment variables are not interpreted for the startup command.

How can I use environment variables to start scripts in an arbitrary location?

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps? The startup script will be in a different location on each machine. The idea is that the _init_ script is run once on initial setup, and every successive login would run the autorun scripts, using the variable pointing to the script directory.

Comment: Sorry, but this still does not make sense, where would I put this? How will it _magically_ find where the script is located? The environment variable should point to the installation directory of the scripts, which, when loaded at login, will find and execute said scripts.